# Why is the enclosing type of a static lambda member incomplete?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++17

I tried to do something similar today. I was surprised it didn't compile.

```
struct Test {
//  v----- Remove me to compile
    //  /*
    static constexpr auto get_test1 = [](Test const& self) {
        return self.test; // error, Test is incomplete
    };
    // */

    // Handwritten version of the lambda
    struct {
        constexpr auto operator() (Test const& self) const {
            return self.test; // ok
        }
    }
    static constexpr get_test2{};

    int test;
};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/g/rQ21WU)

It says that the `Test` type is incomplete in the scope. Yet the handwritten version of the lambda does indeed work. What is the technical reason for that? Is it an oversight in the standard, or is there a specific wording that makes `Test` incomplete in the lambda?

Comment: It seems both will be OK since [CWG 1836](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1836).

Comment: @xskxzr not sure if related at all, I'm not even using trailing return type

Comment: Note the second change, the subexpression before dot is not required to be of a complete class type any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I could find:

> §5.1.2 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]
>
> 5. [...] [ Note:  Names referenced in the lambda-declarator are looked up in the context in which the lambda-expression appears. —end note ]
> 6. The lambda-expression’s compound-statement yields the function-body (8.4) of the function call operator, but for purposes of name lookup
>      (3.4), [...] the compound-statement is considered in the context of
>      the lambda-expression.

If I am not misreading the standard this means that `Test` and `self` both in the parameter as well in the body are looked/considered in the context of the lambda, which is the class scope in which `Test` is incomplete.

As for why it is allowed with the nested class:

> §9.2 Class members [class.mem]
>
> 2. A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing } of the classspecifier . Within the
>      class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within
>      function bodies, default arguments, using-declarations introducing
>      inheriting constructors (12.9), exception-specification s, and
>      brace-or-equal-initializer s for non-static data members (including
>      such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete
>      within its own class member-specification.

Comment: @xskxzr Read again: "brace-or-equal initializer s for *non-static* data members"

Answer (score 0):

I think that your compiler is correct. `Test` is still incomplete. The processing of such a data member’s initializer (which is what requires the type to be complete) is not deferred until the end of the class definition.

I couldn't find the part of the Standard that deals with this issue, but I remember it was raised as a National Body comment of the C++17 draft (US 24, [P0488R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0488r0.pdf)):

> The current specification prohibits `constexpr static` data members that are of the same type as the 
>   enclosing class.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>    int val;
>    static constexpr A cst = { 42 };  // error
> };
> ```

Apparently, lifting completely the restriction may have caused some breaking changes so that the comment "did not increase consensus".

Comment: `get_test1` is not of the same type as the enclosing class

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know. But the enclosing class is used for initialization. In my understanding the situation is the same.

Comment: @metalfox no the enclosing class is not used for initialization. I have a function parameter that is the same of the enclosing class.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot You are initializing a closure object `get_test1` in a way that requires `Test` to be complete, and it is not at that point, I think.

Comment: @metalfox I have difficulty understanding how `get_test1` is different than `get_test2`. Both are closure object, both require `Test` to be complete, but the one with the nice syntax fails.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Nested classes are an exception to the rule in 9.2.2  quoted by bolov, but lambdas are different entities. I agree that that seems inconstent.